# Remote File Server and access

Tags: windows

We have two main sites. We have a site to site link between our two sites and we have some file servers at our primary site.

I am interested in taking one of our file servers and having a copy available at our second site in case that link goes down.

What is the best way to set up a file server at the second site which will keep data synchronized between the two sites but allow us to present a drive letter with the contents at the second site so they don't need to go over the link for everything?

Let's say I am presenting a drive letter 'X' from FileServer1. Right now, at the second site, users have the 'X' drive mapped and it points to FileServer1.

Is there a best practice for setting up a 'RemoteFileServer1' which has the data from 'X' replicated to it (I'm guessing DFS Replication?) and then have users at the remote site accesss that drive?

Comment: Yes, DFS is what you're looking for here.

Comment: @joeqwerty You should write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed configure DFS and setup DFS replication. make sure your clients connect to the DFS-share and not directly to the server share.

Before setting this up, you can open 'Active Directory Sites and Services' and define the sites and subnets for both locations. This helps your clients to figure out which connection cost the least.